# Installed Luarock - No .lua files

Tags: lua, luarocks

Im a bit of a luarocks noob, but have done a fair bit of lua coding. I can't find the answer to this anywhere;

Ive installed a new luarock (lua-resty-auto-ssl) via:

```
luarocks install --tree lualib lua-resty-auto-ssl
```

This installs to my directory with no problems, however I don't have any .lua files.

I can see in the rock_manifest file they are all listed.

How do I install the .lua files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running `luarocks install --tree lualib lua-resty-auto-ssl`, I have a directory with the following content:

```
lualib
lualib/share
lualib/share/lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/storage_adapters
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/storage_adapters/redis.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/storage_adapters/file.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/jobs
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/jobs/renewal.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/vendor
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/vendor/shell.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/vendor/sockproc
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/vendor/letsencrypt.sh
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/storage.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/ssl_certificate.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/init.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/servers
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/servers/challenge.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/servers/hook.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/utils
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/utils/run_command.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/utils/shell_execute.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/utils/start_sockproc.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/init_worker.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/ssl_providers
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/ssl_providers/lets_encrypt.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/shell
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/shell/start_sockproc
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/auto-ssl/shell/letsencrypt_hooks
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/http_headers.lua
lualib/share/lua/5.3/resty/http.lua
lualib/lib64
lualib/lib64/luarocks
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/manifest
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-auto-ssl
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-auto-ssl/0.9.0-1
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-auto-ssl/0.9.0-1/rock_manifest
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-auto-ssl/0.9.0-1/lua-resty-auto-ssl-0.9.0-1.rockspec
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-auto-ssl/0.9.0-1/doc
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-auto-ssl/0.9.0-1/doc/CHANGELOG.md
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-auto-ssl/0.9.0-1/doc/LICENSE.txt
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-auto-ssl/0.9.0-1/doc/README.md
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-http
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-http/0.09-0
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-http/0.09-0/rock_manifest
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-http/0.09-0/lua-resty-http-0.09-0.rockspec
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-http/0.09-0/doc
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-http/0.09-0/doc/README.md
lualib/lib64/luarocks/rocks/lua-resty-http/0.09-0/doc/LICENSE
```

There are plenty of Lua files there. What result do you get?

(I don't think it will matter much, but: I'm using Lua 5.3 with LuaRocks 2.3.0)

Comment: On Windwos I can install only lua-resty-http. :)

Comment: Thanks! I had a permission problem